# Comparing items in checkedlistbox to items in a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, checklistbox

I have a set of string arrays that I want to compare to the items of a checkedlistbox.I have two checkedlistboxes.The first one has three boxes idari(administratives),tumu(all),and teknik(technicals).The second checkedlistbox contains all of the names (both administratives and technicals).I want only the names that are in the idari string array to be checked when I check idari.And the same goes for teknik and tumu.This is my code but it just keeps on checking all of the items when I check idari.Can anyone give me an idea of whats wrong with my code?Also I'm having problems calling the function the chklstbox_bolum method.

```
    string[] tumu = { "Jane", "Tom", "Danny", "John", "Jacyln", "Lily", "Lale" };
    string[] idari = { "Jane", "Tom", "Danny" };
    string[] teknik = {  "John", "Jacyln", "Lily", "Lale"};

    private void idari_secimi()
    { //function 


        if (chklstbx_bolum.GetItemChecked(1) == false)//if the idari check box has been checked in the checked list box
        {


                for (int i = 0; i < chklstbx_sonuc.Items.Count; i++){
                    for (int j = 0; j < idari.Length; j++)
                    {

                        if (chklstbx_sonuc.SelectedItem.ToString()==idari[j])
                        {
                            chklstbx_sonuc.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                        }
                        else { }
                    }
                    }
        }
        else if (chklstbx_bolum.GetItemChecked(1) == true)
        {//unchecks all the items in the second checked list box when unchecking idari in the first checked list box.
            for (int i = 0; i < chklstbx_sonuc.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                chklstbx_sonuc.SetItemChecked(i, false);

            }
        }
    }


    private void chklstbx_bolum_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {




        if (chklstbx_bolum.GetItemChecked(2) == false)
            tumu_secimi();
          //if the tumu box is checked call this function

        else if (chklstbx_bolum.GetItemChecked(1) == false)

            idari_secimi();
          //if the idari box is checked call this function

        else if (chklstbx_bolum.GetItemChecked(0) == false)

            teknik_secimi();
      //if the teknik box is checked call this function
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
if (chklstbx_sonuc.SelectedItem.ToString()==idari[j])
```

Say you have selected one of the items in chklstbx_sonuc, and you then check something in the bolum list, you will then loop over all items in sonuc, and if the selected item in the sonuc list equals any of the ones in idari, you will check all the items in sonuc.

So you should do this instead:

```
if(chklstbx_bolum.SelectedItem.ToString()==idari[j])
```

On a side note, I suggest you look up WPF/XAML for a simpler way of handling your GUI, and LINQ, for some very powerful handling of enumerables.

Comment: I tried that but its still checking all the items and chklstbx_sonuc is the second checked list box and chklstbx_bolum is the first checked list box.